# Are we graduating from private beta?

Tags: discussion, beta, stackexchange

We are now 33 days into the Private Beta, so 2 days before we can graduate! And it seems that there are some weird things that should only happen in the public beta:

First, in Area51's top communities list, for some of our users such as Rydwolf (imaged below), PLDI now appears!
[image]

Second, looking at the image above, there is now colors. There is also now project results after the mandated 180 days of public beta!

Third, there is no longer a banner linking to the meta on the site (see image below):

[image]

So, are we going to be graduating from Private Beta!? Either a response from SE confirming or denieing this or a response from a normal user to say if they have seen this happen before and what they thik it means is welcome.

Comment: That's not 2 days until we can graduate, that's 2 days left _to_ graduate. More specifically, "The site will have up to 5 weeks to qualify for Public Beta" means that the 35 days is a deadline, rather than a minimum waiting period. Still, hopefully the removal of the meta banner means we're on the right track to be graduated either today or tomorrow.